# correct syntax to add a relationship constraint to Access 2007 DB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

Looking for the correct syntax for this query...

```
"ALTER TABLE [Test_St] ADD CONSTRAINT [FKTestNameStIDTestStID] FOREIGN KEY ([ID]) REFERENCES [Test_Name] ([St_ID])"
```

with the addition of NO INDEX

My understanding is that...

To prevent the automatic creation of indexes for foreign keys, the modifier NO INDEX can be used. (per MS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

ALTER TABLE [Test_St] ADD CONSTRAINT [FKTestNameStIDTestStID] FOREIGN KEY NO INDEX ([ID]) REFERENCES [Test_Name] ([St_ID])"